# Can't log in to a site with Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cookies, http-headers, puppeteer

When I try to log in to the sisal.it site with puppeteer the http login request fails and returns error code 403 (Forbidden), making the login request with the same account but with a browser opened manually the request is successful. If I even open the browser with puppeteer and perform the login procedures manually, the request fails

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation']
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  // Navigate to the page that will perform the tests.
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 1024});
  await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none",
    "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://areaprivata.sisal.it"

  });
  await page.goto('https://chrome.google.com/webstore');
  await page.waitForNavigation();
  await page.goto('https://areaprivata.sisal.it/loginJwt');
  await page.waitForSelector('input[name="usernameEtc"]');
  await page.type('input[name="usernameEtc"]', 'TEST');
  await page.keyboard.press('Tab');
  await page.keyboard.down('Shift');
  await page.keyboard.type('t');
  await page.keyboard.up('Shift');
  await page.keyboard.type('est'); 
  await page.click('#buttonAuth');
})();
```

I tried passing several args and headers before performing the login as you can see from the code above.
If I pass these arguments it doesn't even send the request, but returns some cors errors.

Comment: Hard to know but I'd guess some form of bot detection is catching this since Puppeteer is a bot. things like how the mouse moves and how fast the keys are pressed could be indicators but it's very difficult to know what they are measuring and probably the second you figure it out is the time they'll change it up a bit

Comment: In my experience, contacting with support team of that website also could help you. Some websites could block accessing through VPN. Or could block the ip address if the request is so faster than human's activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, sisal.it has implemented strict detection methods to prevent automated access, particularly for actions such as logging in. This is a common challenge when using automation tools like Puppeteer, but there are several steps you can take to make your script more resilient and mimic human behavior more closely.

Firstly, consider integrating `puppeteer-extra` along with the `puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth` plugin. This plugin is designed to evade several common detection techniques by applying numerous evasion techniques automatically. Install the necessary packages and adjust your code as follows:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation']
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    // Your existing code to navigate and login
})();
```

Also, your current approach of setting custom HTTP headers is a step in the right direction, but it's essential to ensure these headers do not inadvertently signal automated access. Pay particular attention to the `User-Agent` string and other signature headers such as `Sec-Fetch-*` which can be closely scrutinized by anti-automation checks. Ideally, capture these headers from a legitimate, human-driven browser session and replicate them in your Puppeteer script as closely as possible.

Also, consider introducing deliberate, randomized delays between keystrokes and actions (such as clicking the login button) to mimic human behavior more convincingly.